# empty function for handleRun of thread.cpp

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef FFMPEG_THREAD_H
 #define FFMPEG_THREAD_H

#include <pthread.h>

class Thread
{
public:
    Thread();
    ~Thread();

    void                        start();
    void                        startAsync();
    int                         wait();

    void                        waitOnNotify();
    void                        notify();
    virtual void                stop();

protected:
    bool                        mRunning;

    virtual void                handleRun(void* ptr);

private:
    pthread_t                   mThread;
    pthread_mutex_t             mLock;
    pthread_cond_t              mCondition;

    static void*                startThread(void* ptr);
};

#endif //FFMPEG_DECODER_H



 void* Thread::startThread(void* ptr)
{

    Thread* thread = (Thread *) ptr;
    thread->mRunning = true;
    thread->handleRun(ptr);
    thread->mRunning = false;

}

void Thread::handleRun(void* ptr)
{
}
```

In this snippet of code, the thread.cpp. Inside the thread object it starts the running and have the HandleRun function but it's empty. What's purpose of the HandleRun empty function?
It does nothing.

Comment: Is `Thread` designed for sub-classing with `handleRun` being `virtual`?  Btw, retagging since this appears to be C++ rather than C.

Comment: so, the default handleRun has stuffs inside and the above snippet subclassing it ?

Comment: The other way round.  I'm guessing that you've shown us the default `handleRun` and that the intention is that sub-classes override this. If you post the class definition for `Thread` (its header), we could say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown enough code to give a definitive answer.  At a guess, `Thread` could be a base class with `handleRun` being `virtual`.

Classes which derived from `Thread` would presumably automatically have a dedicated thread created with `handleRun` acting as its entrypoint.